# Curl outgoing port & proxies

Tags: php, curl, proxy

My host only allows me to use curl over the outgoing port 80. My proxy only has port 735 open. I thought this would be an easy one, **CURLPORT_PORT** set to 80 and **CURLOPT_PROXYPORT** set to 735. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work without changing host or proxy?

> I get error 28 - connect() timed out.

My current script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '80');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I changed proxy provider as I tried everything I found on getting this sorted, but it didn't work.